# Asynchronous data manipulation inside Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller which receives a data object asynchronously:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('melon')
        .controller('AdminPage3Ctrl', Controller);

    Controller.$inject = ['BPsFactory'];

    function Controller(BPsFactory) {
        var page3ctrl = this;
        page3ctrl.headerTitle = "Manage Boundary Partners";
        page3ctrl.boundaryPartners = [];

        activate();
        console.log(page3ctrl)
        console.log(page3ctrl.countries);

        function activate() {
            return getBPs();
        }

        function getBPs() {
            return BPsFactory.getBPs()
            .then(function(data) {
                page3ctrl.boundaryPartners = data;
                var countries = [];
                angular.forEach(page3ctrl.boundaryPartners, function(value, key) {
                    countries.push(value.country);
                });
                page3ctrl.countries = countries.unique();
                return page3ctrl.boundaryPartners;
            })
        }
    }
})();
```

I need to extract some information from this `data` object to use in an `ng-repeat` in my view, namely, an array of country names filled with *unique values only*. For that, I am using the following `Array.prototype` methods:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(v) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === v) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(!arr.contains(this[i])) {
            arr.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

However, in the code sample above, while `page3ctrl.countries` is defined and filled with the correct values on the first `console.log`:

```
Object {headerTitle: "Manage Boundary Partners", boundaryPartners: Array[0], countries: Array[0]}boundaryPartners: Array[4]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]countries: Array[3]0: "Worldwide"1: "Denmark"2: "Mozambique"length: 3__proto__: Array[0]headerTitle: "Manage Boundary Partners"__proto__: Controller
```

The second one outputs `undefined`.

How can I access `page3ctrl.countries` on my `ng-repeat`?

Comment: It's because it's an async method and your console is filling in the object once it comes back (trying to be helpful) - also, your Array prototype methods already exist (`.contains` is basically `.indexOf` - and `.unique` is `.some`)

Comment: But how would I refactor the code so that I can get all the info on time in this specific situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are console.logging before the promise is resolved.

In function getBPs you are returning a promise and telling javascript to continue execution even though the .then method has not been run yet. Here is how I would do it:

```
 function Controller(BPsFactory) {
    var page3ctrl = this;
    page3ctrl.headerTitle = "Manage Boundary Partners";
    page3ctrl.boundaryPartners = [];

    activate();
    //console.log(page3ctrl)
    //console.log(page3ctrl.countries);

    function activate() {
    //Why are you returning this???
      //  return getBPs();
      getBPs();
    }

    function getBPs() {
        return BPsFactory.getBPs()
        .then(function(data) {
            page3ctrl.boundaryPartners = data;
            var countries = [];
            angular.forEach(page3ctrl.boundaryPartners, function(value, key) {
                countries.push(value.country);
            });
            page3ctrl.countries = countries.unique();
            console.log(page3ctrl)
            //Why are you returning this???
            //return page3ctrl.boundaryPartners;

        })
    }
}
```

In your controllers template you could now do something like this(Assuming you are using ControllerAs: page3)

```
<div ng-repeat="country in page3.countries">
 <!-- Do country stuff here -->
</div>
```

Comment: You actually don't even need to return the promise in getBPs() you just need to execute you factory method and once the getBPs fetch is done .then runs and your scope variables will bind.